# How do I make an initComponent object require something to be passed in to it?

Tags: java, swing, init

I have a view with a JList, and want to add things to it manually.
I've created a DefaultListModel like suggested on other sites, but I can't pass it in to the JList because it's in initComponents which is protected.
I tried changing it manually by opening the .java file in notepad++, but when I ran my project I got a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataModel must be non null" exception on start-up, so I changed it back.
Is there an option in the JFrame properties that would allow me to set the JList to require a DefaultListModel to be passed in, or am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: This is obviously build using Netbeans form designer.  AFTER the `initComponents` method, simply create a new `DefaultListModel` and apply it to the `JList` you created... something like `jList1.setModel(myFunkyNewModel)` ... for example

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, setModel did the trick.